# I need a way to create an action for github

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions

The scenario is that I'm working in a company that uses a GitLab Empresarial account so that we can perform commits and work with it.

But I have a personal account on GitHub and GitLab, I need a way that I can create an action that makes the work account commits count in my personal account (could be either GitHub or GitLab).

Because I don't want my account to be "stopped" and without the count of commits, for the portfolio, I believe this is not good.

Comment: ASFAIK github accounts are always personal and not company-managed. You can become part of a company (and thus have access to private repos of that company), but the account is personal and will not be deleted, even if you quit that company.

Comment: But in this company it's mandatory to use the GitLab account they gave me, I wanted a way to make the commits from that account count in my personal account (note: I can't use any other account than the GitLab account they gave me)

Comment: I commit to internal Git repositories all the time, that doesn't make me or anyone in the same position any less of a developer. I'm not sure why everyone is so concerned about their GitHub timeline when most developers' contributions aren't to GitHub and don't appear in this visualization. In any event, I'm not sure how your employer/client would feel if you had your own personal accounts have access to their properietary codebases - probably *way* more of a headache than it's worth.

Comment: "I don't want my account to be "stopped" and without the count of commits, for the portfolio I believe this is not good." Are you saying that checking public GitHub account activity is used for hiring decisions, where you live/work? Really?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the activity in the profile, along with the projects and the well-written Readme could be good for the portfolio.

Comment: @blackbird It can't hurt, but I also think it's somewhat irrational to put too much weight into that specific part of your profile.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I believe this is a reasonable assumption. Maybe not about commits to private repositories (a possible new employer would at most see the _number_ of commits done, not their quality), but checking an applicants contribution to a project may give an understanding of how he/she writes code. Quite often I have seen people mentioning their github projects in a resume.

Comment: @PMF I know about having “portfolios” of either side project or open source work. That makes sense. But sheer number of commits? That doesn’t seem to make sense. There are tools readily available that will generate you a repo with commits that make your green activity chart spell out any pixel art you’d like. You can trivially just create commits to private repos; they’re meaningless.

Comment: @Alexander Yes, I fully agree. That's what I wrote above. Maybe the OP isn't aware of this.